# How to get DOM Window Object in Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to access a map object which is attached to the window, and has many methods. My goal is to be able to execute these methods in Selenium Java. For example, if I have window.map.someFunction(2), I beed to be able to retrieve the returned value of this.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can always use JavascriptExecutor
For example I am adding the link below

https://www.guru99.com/execute-javascript-selenium-webdriver.html